# The tag "xxx" does not exist in xml namespace clr-namespace. Not able to Publish WPF visual c# project

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, visual-c#-express-2010

Am a newbie to c# application development. Am currently working on a project in visual c# express 2010. Am able to run the project without any errors and everything works fine. But when i try to publish the project to a directory i get these following errors and i am not able to figure out the solution. Kindly help.

> Error 6   The tag 'AutoCompleteBox' does not exist in XML namespace
>   'clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit'.
>   Line 20 Position 10.  C:\Users\Thangamani\Desktop\BACKSTROKE
>   LABS\DILRAJ\DILRAJ BETA
>   VERSION\WpfApplication_BETA\WpfApplication_BETA\Cust_Profile_View.xaml    20  10  WpfApplication_BETA
>
> Error 5   The tag 'BarcodeProfessional' does not exist in XML namespace
>   'clr-namespace:Neodynamic.WPF;assembly=Neodynamic.WPF.Barcode'. Line
>   13 Position 10.   C:\Users\Thangamani\Desktop\BACKSTROKE
>   LABS\DILRAJ\DILRAJ BETA
>   VERSION\WpfApplication_BETA\WpfApplication_BETA\Cust_IDCard.xaml  13  10  WpfApplication_BETA

Comment: i have also installed wpf toolkit using PM.

Comment: Make sure all your assembly references (to WPF toolkit and other third parties) are set to Copy Local = true.

Comment: @HighCore Thanks a lot. Solved most of the errors. Still am getting one error.       "The type or namespace name 'Fluent' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" Can you please tell me which package i need to install to solve this error?

Comment: Sounds like another third party. I couldn't tell because I don't know what references you're using, but the same as before: make sure you specify Copy Local = true in all third parties.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, go to the **Configuration Manager** to check every project is using the platform you're using to build, for example, if you publish with `Release` Mode and using `Any CPU`, Check evey project to `Any CPU`.

[image]